# how to merge two dict to one

Tags: python, python-2.7

if I have 2 dict:

```
d1={1:[2,3,str],2:[4,5,str2]}
d2={3:[6,7],2:[8,9]}
```

and I want to create a new dictionary that will contain only the keys that appear in both dictionaries

```
new_d={2:[4,5,str2,8,9]}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "how to marge two dict to one" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: @JörgWMittag why is an example absolutely required? Sometimes you don't even know where to start.

Comment: @MarkRansom: For one, it shows that the OP actually put any effort into solving the problem themselves. I fully agree that there *are* examples of well-researched, well-phrased, well-formatted, extremely valuable, outstanding questions here on this site that don't contain any code, but I will submit that this particular question is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{k: d1[k] + d2[k] for k in set(d1.keys()).intersection(d2.keys())}
```

This construct `{... for ... in ... }` is called a dictionary comprehension.

The `.keys()` are not really needed in both cases but they make it clearer what's happening. The shortest version is:

```
{k: d1[k] + d2[k] for k in set(d1) & set(d2)}
```

The `&` operator is roughly equivalent to `.intersection` for sets, and `set(d1)` works because iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys.